# Wordpress: False function re-declare error?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know php, but very new to wordpress. and I just don't want to learn this stuff, only need to change something for a short while,

I am declaring a function in file

`var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php`

```
function cr (){   

}
```

But wordpress gives me error

> Can't redeclare function cr() (previously declared on line no..xxx) in file ....

now the line number it mentions is the only place where this function is declared, This is what I tried :

1. tried to rename the function to very uncommon names and every time the same error.
2. wrapped the function in

   `if(!function_exists('cr')) {
       function cr() {
           .. 
           ..
       }
   }`

I get an error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function cr() in
>   /var/www/storearn/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php
>   on line 74

What could be the reason?

Comment: downvoter? care to comment ?

Comment: Why do you want to declare the function in the `thankyou.php` file?

Comment: You can't declare functions conditionally (though you can conditionally declare anonymous functions as needed).  Also, `cr` is a terrible name for a function.  Give your functions meaningful names.

Comment: thanks for sharing best practices, though they don't tell me anything about why wordpress says, the function is already declared! Please note I already mentioned that I have tried so many (meaningful and meaningless too) names but wordpress says it's already declared.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the function in the wrong file.

Firstly, template files are the wrong place to declare a function. It belongs either within a custom plugin or your theme (functions.php or some file included from there). Ideally a custom plugin but it would depend on context. With the plugin placed in the right location there shouldn't be any risk of it being duplicated. You may also want to prefix it too.

The second issue I see is that you're attempting to modify files within the WooCommerce plugin itself. As soon as you update WC, those modifications will be overwritten. Templates should be overridden individually within your theme.

Documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: thanks for sharing best practices, but why it says function is already declared!

Comment: Follow the process outlined and you won't have that problem. It could be that the template is loaded in an unexpected way, that you have a function elsewhere with the same name or a handful of other similar problems. All of these issues are resolved by doing things the right way